# I can't create a pod in minikube on windows

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a pod for a project's api from a yaml file. The pod will be created from an image that I already have in docker desktop and docker hub. I've even pulled this image to minikube, and even so, I can't create the pod and it stays in Back-off status, and gives an error, logs:

```
Normal   Scheduled  66s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/api-farmacia to minikube
Normal   Pulling    66s                kubelet            Pulling image "erivan41/app-farma:1.0"
Normal   Pulled     46s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "erivan41/app-farma:1.0" in 20.344s (20.344s including waiting)
Normal   Created    23s (x3 over 45s)  kubelet            Created container api-farmacia-container
Normal   Pulled     23s (x2 over 40s)  kubelet            Container image "erivan41/app-farma:1.0" already present on machine
Normal   Started    22s (x3 over 45s)  kubelet            Started container api-farmacia-container
Warning  BackOff    3s (x3 over 34s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container api-farmacia-container in pod api-farmacia_default(0c6c4ce3-d2b1-4a33-a400-75e1408e3b66)
```

I expected it to stay in Running but it stays in status CrashLoopBackOff